# "phing.types.Path doesn't support nested text data" - what does it mean?

Tags: php, ant, build-process, phing

I have the following Phing configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="ru.fractalizer.phpsweetpdo" default="make-phar-packages" basedir="..">

    <target name="run-tests-library" description="Running all the tests">
        <phpunit>
            <formatter type="plain" usefile="false"/>
            <batchtest>
                <classpath>.</classpath>
                <fileset dir="tests/Library">
                    <include name="**/*Test*.php"/>
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>
        </phpunit>
    </target>
```

But executing Phing build on this target gives me error:

> Execution of target "run-tests-library" failed for the following
>   reason: Z:\Work\PHP\phpSweetPDO\phing\build.xml:5:17: phing.types.Path
>   doesn't support nested text data.
>
> BUILD FAILED Z:\Work\PHP\phpSweetPDO\phing\build.xml:5:17:
>   phing.types.Path doesn't support nested text data. Total time: 9.0173
>   seconds

I don't understand the message. What exactly is not supported?

5:17 is the line where `"<phpunit>"` tag is written.

Comment: Maybe this line is related?: http://www.phing.info/trac/browser/trunk/classes/phing/IntrospectionHelper.php?rev=311#L365

Comment: @hakre Yes, it seems so. But I would prefer error messages to be more clear and understandable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your classpath definition:

```
<classpath>.</classpath>
```

The nested text is the single `.`.  You can define a path in various ways:

- Nested `pathelement` elements.
- Nested `fileset`, `dirset`, and other resource collection elements.
- In-line using the `path` attribute.

For your simple case, perhaps

```
<classpath path="." />
```

would be the way to go.

See the [*Path-like Structures*](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path) section in the the Ant docs.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution worked. But I should say, that Phing error messages aren't very clear and accurate ;)